# Does getting firebase reference add to the billing of data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

```
viewsReference.updateChildValues(dict) { (error, ref) in
        completion()
    }
```

I have this method, the closure returns ref. Which is data. my question is does it amount to the billing of downloaded data. im trying to minimize pulling data in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DatabaseReference` does not contains any data, so whether you return it or no can't have any impact on the data downloaded and thus on how much you're charged for the operation.